# h:commandLink 1º time never work

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, seam

I´m trying to call a bottom in jsf with a h:commandLink to download a PDF from the bean.

Basically like this:

```
@Begin(join = true)
    public void generatePDF() throws Exception {
         //create pdf on page
}

<h:commandLink action="#{bean.generatePDF()}"/>
```

but any time i start the server and click from the first time or pass a long time without action on server it gives:

```
WARN  [SeamPhaseListener] uncaught exception, passing to exception handler
  org.jboss.seam.ConcurrentRequestTimeoutException: Concurrent call to conversation
  at org.jboss.seam.core.Manager.restoreAndLockConversation(Manager.java:641)
  at org.jboss.seam.core.Manager.restoreConversation(Manager.java:603)
  at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterRestoreView(SeamPhaseListener.java:392)
  at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterServletPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:230)
  at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.afterPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:196)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:175)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:114)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:102)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
  ...
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active conversation context
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try removing the conversation initialization i.e. remove `@Begin` from your method.

Comment: It give the same error

Comment: How this could give the same error since you're now not starting a new conversation, but should use the old conversation (if any)?

Comment: I don´t know (is create a new conversation @create) but only do on the 1º time this method it's call, then never happen again, only if i restart the server.